# How do I engineer the equivalence of graph-connectedness of an orbit and topological space connectedness?

Tags: general-topology, functions, connectedness, group-actions

Let $X,d$ be Hausdorff and let the level sets of a function $f:X\to X$ converge to their image - in other words, $x$ is a limit point of the set $f^{-1}(\{x\})$.

Is the directed graph of the orbit of $f$ in $X$ graph-connected if and only if $X,d$ is connected?

Seems reasonable. I can't find a counterexample. But I'm a novice at topology.

My intuition seems to say that, given the property in this question's first sentence, then what I really need to do is to make a topology on $X$ which says that a subset $Y$ is closed if and only if forall $x\in Y$, $Y$ is closed if and only if $f(x)$ is also in $Y$.

But I have no idea whether that coincides with $f:X,d\to X,d$ being function on a Hausdorff topology having a graph-connected orbit.

Comment: Should $f$ be continuous? What does "the level sets of $f$ converge to their image" mean exactly - does that mean that for every $x\in X$, the point $x$ is a limit point of the set $f^{-1}(\{x\})$? Finally, is $d$ a metric or an arbitrary topology?

Comment: @NoahSchweber by "level sets converge to their image" I certainly mean your proposition, and possibly something stronger. Perhaps: "$x$ is the only accumulation point of $f^{-1}(\{x\})$".  Is that slightly stronger than what you put?

Comment: @NoahSchweber re continuity, I'm struggling because I think if $f$ is continuous and the level set of every $x$ accumulates to $x$ then we must also have that $f(x)=x$, and I know that not to be the case. So on that basis I think this will need to be a not necessarily continuous function - if I assume continuity I have an immediate contradiction.

Comment: @NoahSchweber finally, in $d$ you may have hit upon a defect in the question because to use $d$ clearly implies a metric.  An answer for a metric space would give me better tools to work with but I also know this is likely not a metric space. In fact it may not even be a nontrivial Haussdorf space. FWIW it's the quotient space $\Bbb N[\frac16]/\langle3\rangle$ with the quotient taken multiplicatively and the function is $f(x)=\langle3\rangle(x+2^{\nu_2(x)}\cdot3^{\nu_3(x)-1})$ & the level sets are of the form $\{\langle3\rangle\cdot(x+(1-2^{-6n})2^{\nu_2(x)}\cdot3^{\nu_3(x)-1}):n\in\Bbb N\}$.